# Calling a web service from console application using threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have to call a web service using threads (each call is on thread) in my console application. The thread count is initially 5 and can change in future for which ie changing thread count I have to use app.config. The problem I am facing is I have to call a web service while looping through 3 tables and table data is not limitied.

```
foreach (DataRow rowclient in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow rowN in ds.Tables[1].Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataRow rowD in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
        {
            poolThread[i] = new Thread(CallP);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
            poolThread[i].Start();
            i++;
            //check whether there is any thread available in pool

        }
```

where `CallP` is the actual method which calls the webservice and I have to wait for thread until one is released.

Now I am getting error

> Index was out side the bounds of the array

I am new to threading so please help me.

Comment: Where is the error being thrown?

Comment: Where do you initialize your `poolThread` collection?

Comment: This is a pretty antiquated approach to your problem...  consider .NET's Task Parallel Library (TPL).  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Especially consider you should use something like TPL so that multiple exceptions can be properly bubbled up under an `AggregateException`.  This approach you're looking at is risky and possible thread unsafe.

Comment: What line throws the IndexOutOfBoundException?  can you post an MCVE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve